# implement another user stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack

I need another stack despite the usual process user stack, eg. one that is explicitely accessable. This would allow a recursive walk to be paused, resumed, splitted and the parts moved from one thread to another for example.

If we have:

```
void recurse(Node& n)
{
    n.calculate();

    for(Node& child: n.children)
        recurse(child);
}
```

we could then do:

```
void recurse(Stack& stack)
{
    Node& n=stack.peek();
    n.calculate();

    for(Node& child: n.children)
    {
        stack.push(child);
        recurse(stack);
        stack.pop();
    }
}
```

The new `recurse` procedure could be transformed to an iterative one, and then extended by pauseing, splitting etc.

However, how to implement `Stack`, if the nodes can be an abitrary, `Node`-derived class, wielding virtual functions and subclass dependent size?

Comment: Do you have to implement it yourself, or are you allowed to use `std::stack<>`?

Comment: The usual solution here is a collection of (smart) pointers to objects, in order to avoid the slicing problem.

Comment: std::stack would be instantiated for one given type, for example `Node`, and then unable to handle any `Node`-derived object of other size guess.

Comment: @dronus That's why you use Node* or something like std::shared_ptr<Node>

Comment: Using pointers and `new` would ignore the FIFO access fashion and thus add much overhead I guess?

Comment: How else do you want to do inheritance? You can use something like boost::any / boost::variant, but that's not what you're asking in the question.

Comment: I will try out `shared_ptr`. However, it would be impossible to feed the stack by a `Node` derivate I guess, because it cannot be duplicated without knowledge of its size at runtime? So I have to pass a `Node*` explicitely, which is than wrapped by `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @dronus Wait what? Why would you wrap a raw pointer in a shared_ptr, nope.jpg.

Comment: If `stack.push(node)` would take a `Node&`, but just store a `shared_ptr` to it, node will die if the calling scope is lost. So `stack.push` has to do a copy of the given node, which is of unknown derivated type. Is this possible?

Comment: What about overloading the `new` and `delete` operator, using an additional `Stack& stack` parameter, providing a Stack class with some momery preallocated, and add some error checks to prevent `delete` to be called on any but the last added element?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `std::stack<Node*>`, or ideally an `owning_pointer<Node>` instead of `Node*`.

Comment: That would not use continous memory in an efficient fashion like the user stack would do, but reserve and free heap memory repeatedly, as the Node subclass entities would have to be reserverd by `new`.